# How to select from refcursor

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, ref-cursor

I'm trying to find better approach for selecting from `REFCURSOR`. Let's say there is a such function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_batches_to_export(p_batch_type varchar2 := NULL) 
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
   o_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN o_cursor FOR
      SELECT batch_id
        FROM batches
       WHERE batch_type = p_batch_type OR p_batch_type IS NULL;
​
   RETURN o_cursor;
END;
```

Now I need to select content from this table using requral select (it is limitation of client application - NiFi usign JDBC connection - it supports only scalar types to be returned, deseralization of `REFCURSOR` fails; also direct select from source table is not possible)

I found this select, it creates XML from REFCURSOR and then extracts values from this XML:

```sql
SELECT extractvalue(value(batches_list),'ROW/BATCH_ID') batch_id
FROM table(xmlsequence(get_batches_to_export())) batches_list
```

Any idea how to avoid the XML part (the xmlsequence, extractvalue and value  function calls)? There is also limitation I cannot create any other helper data types or objects - only select can be used.

Comment: You aren't supposed to **select** from a ref cursor.  You **fetch** from it.  In JDBC I think you use the `next` method to fetch the rows.

Comment: I would expect there could be a function, that would do similar thing like xmlsequence, which produces result consumable by function table.

Comment: But what would be the data type of the return value of such a function?  A ref cursor can return anything at all.